# Passing parameters to a function from the Bash command line

Tags: c++, linux, bash

I am running a C++ program from the command line on Bash, which is in a Linux environment. I am curious how you pass in a parameter from the command line. Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int large_pow2( int n );

int main()
{
   int value = 15;
   int largest_power = large_pow2(value);

   cout << "The highest power of 2 in " << value << " is " << large_power << "." << endl;

   return 0;
} 

int large_pow2( int n )
{
   int i = n
   int j = i & (i - 1);
   while( j != 0)
   {
      i = j;
      j = i & (i - 1);
   }
   return j;
}
```

After I compile the program I want to be able to use the command line to pass in a number to use for `value`. For instance, to run the program you type `./"program_name"` where `"program_name"` is the name of my program without quotes. Is there a way to set `value = n` or something? When I run the program let's say I want `n` to be `20` so on the command line I type something like `./"program_name" 20`. Then the program would run with `n = 20`. Is there a way to do that? I am completely new to a Linux environment and Bash so don't quite know how to do things in it yet.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function . Pay attention to the description of the `main`s parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `argc` and `argv` in `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` and modify your code accordingly.

The `argc` arguments tracks the number of arguments passed to your program from `CLI` and is always >=1. When `1` it is it name of program. So `argc[0]` is program name.

`argv` holds the command line arguments, other than program name and is always char string. Hence we need to use appropriate converter like `atoi`, if you don't want string.

So your code will look like, error checking not done for simplicity

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Now we expect argc ==2, program value, This will when argc != 2
    // We should use if in real scenario
    assert(argc == 2);
    int value = atoi(argv[1])
    int largest_power = large_pow2(value);

    cout << "The highest power of 2 in " << value << " is " << large_power << "." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I am curious though, if I am just trying to pass in an integer parameter, then why do I need a `char []`?

Comment: Updated in the answer. Please have a look

Comment: Okay that makes a lot of sense. Another question (Sorry for the many questions, I am just trying to understand this for future reference), I get that `argc` tacks the number of arguments passed into the program, but why is it never used? For instance, `argv` is in the header of main, but then we use it in the initialization of `value`. Does my question make sense? I apologize if it is worded in a confusing way.

Comment: No problem for many question, In fact, we do use argc in real program, Ignore here for simplicity. May be I should update the answer. Adding an `assert` now

Comment: So the name of the program is itself `1` argument and the value I am passing into it is a second argument hence why `argc = 2`?

Answer (score 1):

Your main method can take (int argc, char** argv) which are the count of arguments and the NUL terminated args.  The program path is argv[0] so atoi(argv[1]) is probably what you want.  Check argc ==2.